# Explicitly print CSRF token field instead of form_rest(form)?

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

How can I **explicitly print CSRF field** instead of using `{{ form_rest(form) }}`?

I need this because I'm going to hide/show some fields based on conditions, however `{{ form_rest(form) }}` is going to print all of the remaining fields (which is what I'd like to avoid).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It can be done this way:

```
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
```

Also you might want to consider adding fields conditionally in your form type instead of making that kind of decisions in a template.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! For conditionally i mean that (for example) if a entity type as no elements inside i'd like to hide from the user and display a message. Do you think s wrong putting this logic in template?

Comment: I don't fully get your example, but, in general, it depends. Now that you know at least two ways of achieving this, you can make a choice in a concrete situation.

Comment: Works like a charm.